# Translating XML request into valid C# code

Tags: c#, xml

I am workign on putting this xml request into c# code. I am trying to hit USPS API to get tracking info sent back for tracking numbers we sent in. I tried hardcoding it into some long strings but realized this is not the most effiecnt and correct way to go about it. I've looked around and saw you can create it using xdoc but dont know how to implement it specifically for my request. Does anyone have any tips/advice as to how to form this xml request in c#?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJqza.jpg)

```
http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=TrackV2&XML=<?xml 
version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<TrackRequest USERID="xxxxxxxx">
<TrackID ID="XXXXXXXXXXXX1"></TrackID>
<TrackID ID="XXXXXXXXXXXX2"></TrackID>
<TrackID ID="XXXXXXXXXXXX3"></TrackID>
</TrackRequest>
```

I want the request to be formed in a smilar way to this.

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument(new XElement(""),
                                           new XElement("" ),
                                           new XElement("", ""),
                                           new XElement("", ""),
                                           new XElement("", ""),
                                           new XElement("", ""),
                                           new XElement("", ""),
                                           new XElement("", " "));
```

But I am unsure how to handle the URL, and what is necessary to properly send the request and receive the valid response.

Comment: posted request as image since I was having difficulties putting xml in the body

Comment: Indent your xml with four spaces to get it to display properly. Also, please show what you have managed to do so it'll be easier to tell what you need to do next.

Comment: Could you put your xml here using "code samle" button, so that everyone can test it if they need?

Comment: added request to the body of the question. i was going to follow a structure similar to

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication90
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string userID = "JohnSmith";
            string[] ids  = {"123456789","123456789","123456789","123456789","123456789","123456789"};

            string header = "http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=TrackV2&XML=";
            string xmlHeader = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?><TrackRequest></TrackRequest>";
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlHeader);

            XElement trackRequest = doc.Root;
            trackRequest.Add(new XAttribute("USERID", userID));
            foreach(string id in ids)
            {
                XElement trackID = new XElement("TrackID", new XAttribute("ID",id));
                trackRequest.Add(trackID);
            }

            string output = header + doc.ToString();

        }
    }
}
```